# How to delete all lines specified in another file

Tags: linux, bash

I have two (sorted) text files:

a.txt

```
1
2
3 
4
```

b.txt

```
1
3
7
```

I want to create a file only listing the lines in `a.txt` where all lines of file `b.txt` are removed. 
So the result should be:

result.txt

```
2
4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep a.txt -F -x -v --file=b.txt                                   
            |  |  |    +                                           
            |  |  |    +--> obtain PATTERN from file                
            |  |  +-------> invert match                           
            |  +----------> force PATTERN to match only whole lines
            +-------------> PATTERN is a set of newline-separated fixed strings
```

*outputs:*

```
2
4
```

Comment: I don't like `a`, `b` either. I might edit to `f1` & `f2` :P On another note, you probably need to use `-x` to match the whole lines.

Comment: @Blue Moon: those are the OP's prerequisites :p Formatting should be better now.

Comment: Brilliant! I'm always impressed by people knowing these kind of tricks.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a.txt and b.txt are already sorted lexically:

```
comm -23 a.txt b.txt
```

Normally `comm` reads two files, which should be sorted lexically, 
and produces three text columns as output: lines only in file1; lines only in file2; and lines in both files.

The options -23 suppress the second and third columns.

Comment: Thanks, i upvoted your answer, but accepted the other. Because that solution worked for me without fuss. Default `comm` is not installed on cygwin.